# One-liner copy file in ruby

Tags: ruby, file

Is there a one-line way to copy a file to another in Ruby, ensuring the files are closed after the operation finishes?

The best I can come up with is this but I'm not sure the files are closed

```
open(ARGV[1], 'w').write(open(ARGV[0]).read)
```

Comment: What are `ARGV[0]` and `ARGV[1]`?

Comment: `system("cp #{ARGV[1]} #{ARGV[0]}")` or something :)

Comment: @sawa Those are file names received on the command line, but they can be any params. I can update the question with file names if needed

Comment: Unclosed files don't matter too much after your process finishes.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev isn't that cheating a bit? :)

Comment: May I ask why you want to do this as a one-liner? This might make your problem less readable.

Comment: @Aziuth that's true, sometimes is better to write in more lines, I just wanted to know if it was feasible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
File.write(ARGV[1], File.read(ARGV[0]))
```

is a bit shorter and will  ensure the files will be closed.

Comment: I would at least add an understandable error message, if ARGV[0] and/or ARGV[1] are nil or empty....